# DEPURAR: Acceder a una Funcion dentro de un Objeto, Con comillas graves/invertidas

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Deseo depurar con comillas invertidas/graves una funcion que se encuentra dentro de un objeto usando comillas invertidas, desearia saber si es posible, ya que deseo agregar la funcion dentro de un texto. mi codigo:

```js
let persona = {
    nombre: "Pedrosio",
    apellido: "Abril",
    edad: 20,
    programador: true,
    objetoa: {
        nombre: "Juan",
        apellido: "Salas",
        age: 24
    },
    funciona: function() {
        console.log(`Hola, Mi nombre es: ${this.objetoa.nombre} ${this.objetoa.apellido} 
        y tengo ${this.objetoa.age}`)
    }
};
console.log(`Hola, Aquí deseao agregar la funcíon dentro del objeto:_________ `);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingresando a la clave del objeto `persona`, así:

```js
let persona = {
    nombre: "Pedrosio",
    apellido: "Abril",
    edad: 20,
    programador: true,
    objetoa: {
        nombre: "Juan",
        apellido: "Salas",
        age: 24
    },
    funciona: function() {
        console.log(`Hola, Mi nombre es: ${this.objetoa.nombre} ${this.objetoa.apellido} y tengo ${this.objetoa.age}`)
    }
};

persona.funciona();
```

O haciendo `return` en tu función para imprimirlo en tu `console.log()`:

```js
let persona = {
    nombre: "Pedrosio",
    apellido: "Abril",
    edad: 20,
    programador: true,
    objetoa: {
        nombre: "Juan",
        apellido: "Salas",
        age: 24
    },
    funciona: function() {
        return `Hola, Mi nombre es: ${this.objetoa.nombre} ${this.objetoa.apellido} y tengo ${this.objetoa.age}`
    }
};

console.log(`Hola, Aquí deseo agregar la función dentro del objeto: ${persona.funciona()}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder ejecutar algo dentro de la plantilla literal que tienes en el `console.log()` debes usar `${}`. También tienes que hacer que tu función `funciona` haga un `return` del texto que quieres concatenar.

```js
let persona = {
    nombre: "Pedrosio",
    apellido: "Abril",
    edad: 20,
    programador: true,
    objetoa: {
        nombre: "Juan",
        apellido: "Salas",
        age: 24
    },
    funciona: function() {
        return `Hola, Mi nombre es: ${this.objetoa.nombre} ${this.objetoa.apellido} 
        y tengo ${this.objetoa.age}`
    }
};
console.log(`Hola, Aquí deseao agregar la funcíon dentro del objeto: ${persona.funciona()}`);
```